# Attaching animations to a single entity using entity generator - A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm creating a bunch of entities using `<a-entity generator>`, but I also want each to animate when an event happens (in this case, a collision). I'm using `<a-mixin>` to define the properties of the entity that I'm making.

Here's the mixin:

```
<a-mixin id="octa" geometry="primitive: octahedron; radius:4" material="src:#asteroid"></a-mixin>
```

And here's the entity generation:

```
<a-entity entity-generator="mixin: octa position; num: 50;"></a-entity>
```

If I put the `<a-animation>` behavior in the `<a-entity-generator>`, every one of the entities animates rather than just a single entity (I get why that happens though). But if I put the animation behavior between `<a-mixin>` tags, nothing happens. Any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the animation component https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation

`<a-mixin id="octa" geometry="primitive: octahedron; radius:4" material="src:#asteroid" animation="attribute: rotation: to: 0 360 0"></a-mixin>`

Comment: Saw this but only after I had already ended up putting the animation in my collision detection component. Thanks though.